# Блок catch не срабатывает (PHP, конструкция try catch)

Tags: php, try-catch

У меня конечно элементарный вопрос, но вот никак не могу понять принцип работы конструкции try-catch на php.

В общем имеем максимально простой код, как внизу.
Функция **checkNum($number)** проверяет является ли число больше или меньше 5.

Функция выполняется в блоке try.

Если в блоке try мы нарочно сделаем какую-то ошибку (например назовем функцию **checkNNNums**, которой не существует), то это по идее должно приводить к исключению и выполнению блока catch.

Действительно появляется ошибка, но код, который в блоке catch не срабатывает, т.е. например мы не видим заложенной в него надписи 'Сработал блок Catch - Сообщение: ', а просто получаем 
*Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function checkNums()*

Мне нужно отработать именно try-catch, понимаю, что есть варианты решения через альтернативные варианты, но нужно именно таким образом.

PHP 7.3

**Код ниже:**

```
<?php
function checkNum($number) {
    if ($number>5) {
      echo "число больше 5";
    } else {
      echo "число меньше 5";
    }
}

try {
  checkNum(7);
  echo 'Сработал блок try';
}


catch(Exception $e) {
  echo 'Сработал блок Catch - Сообщение: ' .$e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Answer (score 6):

> Если в блоке try мы нарочно сделаем какую-то ошибку (например назовем функцию checkNNNums, которой не существует), то это по идее должно приводить к исключению

Совершенно верно для вашей версии PHP. (не уверен в своей памяти и быстро проверить не удалось, вероятно для всех PHP 7.0 и новее)

Ваше заблуждение и ошибка в том, что вы ожидаете генерацию исключения класса `Exception`. Возможно вы считаете что все исключения наследованы от `Exception`. И как раз вот это неверно. Исключение в этом случае генерируется класса `Error` и этот класс в своём дереве наследования не опирается на `Exception`. Дерево наследования исключений в PHP7.0 и новее [выглядит так](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php7.php):

```
Throwable
  Error
    ArithmeticError
      DivisionByZeroError
    AssertionError
    CompileError
      ParseError
    TypeError
      ArgumentCountError
  Exception
```

И если вы замените свой `catch` на:

```
catch(\Throwable $e) {
```

То он уже будет ловить эту ошибку в вашей версии PHP.

---

Тем не менее обратите внимание, что не все ошибки PHP заменены на генерацию исключений. Механизм ошибок и исключений не связаны друг с другом.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы отловить ошибку, необходимо её выбросить через `throw new Exception();`

```
<?php

function checkNum($number) {
    if ($number>5) {
      echo "число больше 5" . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
      echo "число меньше 5" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$validFunctionName = 'checkNum';
$invalidFunctionName = 'checkNum1';

// Успешно выполнится
try {
    if (!function_exists($validFunctionName))
        throw new Exception('Метод не найден.');

    $validFunctionName(7);
    echo 'Сработал блок try' . PHP_EOL;

} catch(Exception $e) {
  echo 'Сработал блок Catch - Сообщение: ' .$e->getMessage();
}

// Выбросит exception
try {
    if (!function_exists($invalidFunctionName))
        throw new Exception('Метод не найден.');

    $invalidFunctionName(7);
    echo 'Сработал блок try' . PHP_EOL;

} catch(Exception $e) {
  echo 'Сработал блок Catch - Сообщение: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
```

Вывод:

```
число больше 5
Сработал блок try
Сработал блок Catch - Сообщение: Метод не найден.
```

---

Если вам необходимо выбросить исключение в методе, то вы можете использовать следующую конструкцию:

```
<?php

function checkNum($number) {
    if ($number>5) {
      echo "число больше 5" . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Число меньше 5');
    }
}

try {
    if (!function_exists('checkNum'))
        throw new Exception('Метод не найден.');

    checkNum(7);

    echo 'Считаем checkNum при аргументе 7' . PHP_EOL;

    checkNum(3);
    echo 'Считаем checkNum при аргументе 3' . PHP_EOL;

} catch(Exception $e) {
  echo 'Сработал блок Catch - Сообщение: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
```

Вывод:

```
число больше 5
Считаем checkNum при аргументе 7
Сработал блок Catch - Сообщение: Число меньше 5
```

Comment: Развернуто и понятно, но про ошибки design time\runtime - нет ни слова =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков , я про эти вещи и сам не знаю. Выдал ответ на основе своего опыта и код стайла, может и не правильно, но других ответов не было, поэтому оставил свой.